# Slurm: automatically requeue a job that reached wall-time limit

Tags: slurm, restart

I am running a job test.sh that has cannot exceed a wall-time of 24h. Since the simulation will take >10 days, I would like to restart it automatically every time it reaches the wall-time limit. I would simply need to have it submit the same test.sh script every time.

I tried

jobid=$(sbatch --parsable test.sh)

scontrol update jobid $jobid dependency=after:$jobid

but the $jobid in scontrol update jobid $jobid is supposed to be a new job. Do you have suggestions? This may not be the way to achieve it..

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I think you can use checkpoints. Don't make changes to the job script. Just modify your main program such that it stops after running for 23hrs and store the results in some checkpoint. Now you can control this with a bash script and a [for loop](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/).

Comment: or, you can ask the admin to allocate you the resources for 10 days.

Answer (score 6):

One easy way is to use the `timeout` command that will stop your program a bit before Slurm does, and will tell you through the return code if the timeout was reached or not. If so, you can requeue it with `scontrol`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --open-mode=append
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#... other Slurm options...

timeout 23h ./the_program 
if [[ $? == 124 ]]; then 
  scontrol requeue $SLURM_JOB_ID
fi
```

The `--open-mode=append` is there to make sure the output of each run is appended to the file chosen by `--output` rather than truncating it at every restart.